# When do Commutative Rings with Identity lack the existence of gcd’s?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I’m aware that not all commutative rings guarantee the existence of gcd’s. The only example I have of this currently is the ring of even integers in which 2 has no divisors and therefore no greatest common divisor. I can’t, however, think of a commutative ring with identity in which this is the case. I know that such an example would need to not be a UFD since UFD’s guarantee the existence of gcd’s. Any ideas?

Comment: [26 commutative rings with identity that aren’t gcd domains](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&L=123). And [5 of them are domains](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=8&L=123) if that matters to you.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful.

Comment: No problem! Glad it is useful.